# undefined reference to `sqlglm' and undefined reference to `sqlcxt'

Tags: c, oracle, precompile

I am trying to compile a pro* c program. Compilation of pro* c file with proc iname=file-name is successful. Now i am compiling the generated .c file but it is throwing below error.

"undefined reference to `sqlglm'"
"undefined reference to`sqlcxt'"

I am using below command to command compile the c file on windows 10.

gcc -o proctest proctest.c -I C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\precomp\sdk\include -L C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\lib

Comment: apparently you are missing some libraries at link time, i.e. some '-l' qualifiers.

Comment: could you please let me know which library i need to add